# Is it possible to print value of TPU cloud variable in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, cloud, tpu

Having disabled eager execution, I am able to connect to my cloud TPU and run my custom training loop. After calculating the loss, I would like to print that variable.

Given that loss is a tensor of a Cloud TPU, I haven't found any way to print it till now. `tf.print` returns a `PrintOperation`, so I am stuck. I guess something like moving the loss tensor back to my cpu would work, but I haven't found any hacky way to do that.

I know it is possible to get that result because when I encapsulate my model with `keras` under a TPU distribution strategy and use `model.fit` instead of my custom training loop, I can get the loss metrics printed.

So there must be a way and any help in finding this is greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, find my hacky way around, even though if better alternatives exist, I would love to hear them:

```
sess = tf.compat.v1.Session()
init_op = tf.compat.v1.global_variables_initializer()
sess.run(init_op)
<tensor>.eval(session=sess)
```

Comment: Did you ever find a proper way of doing this?

Comment: @SantoshGupta7 haha, no.

Comment: I've just got error: "RuntimeError: The Session graph is empty.  Add operations to the graph before calling run()."